# Implement IDisposable for NinjectControllerFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

How do I implement IDisposable for my Ninject??

I am attaching the code. I am new that is why kind of lost on what to do, please explain me as well.

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;
    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
          ? null
          : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }
}
```

Comment: If this is for an MVC app, why not just use the Ninject MVC extension?

Comment: @TrevorPilley, what if I continue working with this Ninject, can you help me writing the IDisposable for it, Please. It is urgent

Comment: does my answer help? if not, you need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is how to dispose of disposable controllers, you need to implement this method in your factory:

```
public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
{
    var disposableController = controller as IDisposable;

    if (disposableController != null)
    {
        disposableController.Dispose();
    }
}
```